# Vue Router v4 HTML5 history mode issue on reload and direct link

Tags: vue.js, apache, .htaccess, vuejs3

I have created a simple example of Vue3 in a subdirectory on my webserver:

```
https://tokant.com/vue-router-transition-v2/
```

Navigating to the different navigational links works as intended, and refreshing the browser on **home** and **about** also works as intended. However on the last two links (that use *Dynamic Route Matching with Params*), there is an issue:
the **main.js** file cannot be retrieved because it becomes relative to the **/users/** path and not the app root.

There must be an issue with my router **createWebHistory** *base* path or .htaccess, however I have tried many possibilities without success.

The router and routes are set up like this:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About },
    { path: '/users/:id', name: 'user', component: User },
    { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', name: 'notfound', component: NotFound }
]
const router = createRouter({
    // 4. Provide the history implementation to use. We are using the hash history for simplicity here.
    history: createWebHistory('/vue-router-transition-v2'),
    routes, // short for `routes: routes`
})
```

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /vue-router-transition-v2/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know why the base path is not used when refreshing pages that use dynamic routes?

Important information: The app is created without a build step.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which link is broken? Ex `https://tokant.com/vue-router-transition-v2/users/1234` points to the wrong router or does not point to your vue app at all

Comment: The last two links in the navigational menu.

Comment: As explained in the post title, direct links to the /users/ path do not work. But you can navigate to these if you first go to home (/) or about (/about). That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations):

"If you deploy to a subfolder, you should use the [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) option of Vue CLI and the related [base property](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#createwebhistory) of the router."

You are missing the publicPath part and not building your application with vue-cli.

Is there any reason why you are deploying the app without building it?
Building you app is essential for minifying your source files, bundling and tree shaking your libraries and cache busting on any new updates you deploy.

If SEO is not important to you, you can switch to [Hash mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode)

Comment: Thank you Johan. As explained the app is built without a build step. Are you sure that using Vue CLI and publicPath will solve my issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, build it and upload your minified sources in the dist folder